# Decode byte string in txt file - Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, byte

there!

I have been looking for an answer for quite a bit, but to no avail... Anyway, I had a numpy ndarray and I saved it in a txt file with ndarray.tostring(), so now in my file I have stuff like

```
"b'\xae\xc9\x91\xff\x9d\x12\xac\xbf\xeasz\xfal\t\xba\xbf\xa18x\xf1\x1bF'"
```

Now I want to decode that so I can apply ndarray.fromstring(byte_string).

How can I achieve it? I already used bytes(byte_string, 'utf-8'), then decode, removing the b and ', etc...

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: For the record, the solution was using 
b = ast.literal_eval(byte_string). Thank you, Andy!

Comment: This is not valid utf-8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to decode it directly from bytes:

```
In [11]: b = b'\xae\xc9\x91\xff\x9d\x12\xac\xbf\xeasz\xfal\t\xba\xbf\xa18x\xf1\x1bF'

In [12]: np.fromstring(b, dtype=np.uint8)
Out[12]:
array([174, 201, 145, 255, 157,  18, 172, 191, 234, 115, 122, 250, 108,
         9, 186, 191, 161,  56, 120, 241,  27,  70], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: I say this mainly as this bytes are not valid utf-8 (they don't decode)

Comment: The issue is that in the text file is already saved as "b'\xae\xc9\x91\xff\x9d\x12\xac\xbf\xeasz\xfal\t\xba\xbf\xa18x\xf1\x1bF'", so when I save it in a variable, it doesn't store it as a BYTES object, but a string.

Comment: @david you can read it as bytes with `b = ast.literal_eval(open(file_name).read())`

Answer (score 1):

Your string is BYTE object.
`str(b'','utf8')`

Comment: I believe it should be `utf-8`

Comment: The issue is that in the text file is already saved as "b'\xae\xc9\x91\xff\x9d\x12\xac\xbf\xeasz\xfal\t\xba\xbf\xa18x\xf1\x1bF'", so when I save it in a variable, it doesn't store it as a BYTES object, but a string.